# How do you call a specific method on a list of instances (using map)?

Tags: python, dictionary, method-call

I have the following class:

```
class Enum(RootFragment):

    def __init__(self, column, packageName, name, modifiers=["public"], enumValues=[]):
        RootFragment.__init__(self, packageName, name, modifiers, "enum")

        self.column = column
        self.enumValues = []

        map(self.addEnumValue, enumValues)

    ... more methods
```

Now I create a number of Enum instances that are put into a dict. This is what gets printed on `print collidingEnums`:

```
{'ManagerRole': <Enum instance at 0x0998F080>, 'StaffMemberRole': <Enum instance at 0x0998B490>}
```

Now because the `<Enum instance at 0x0998F080>` is not very useful I'd like to call the `getName` method on each instance. I was trying:

```
print ", ".join(map(Enum.getName, collidingEnums.items())),
```

but this gave me an error saying:

```
TypeError: unbound method getName() must be called with Enum instance as first argument (got tuple instance instead)
```

Eeh? How do you call the `getName` method here? Is it possible that way at all?

Comment: Sorry, i meant, use `getattr(object, "__name__")`

Comment: Your problem in this particular case is that you're calling `dict.items()`, which returns `(key, value)` tuples. If you were calling `dict.values()` this particular example would work. However, to make it work for values that don't all have the same type, use the list comprehension in Amber's suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `map`. Use a generator expression instead:

```
print ", ".join(i.getName() for i in collidingEnums.values())
```

---

Alternatively, you could simply define your own `__repr__` method for your `Enum` class, which is what Python uses to determine what you print out if you just try to print the class.

```
class Enum(RootFrament):

    # ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.getName()
```

Comment: `i.getName() for i in collidingEnums.items()` gives "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'getName'"... changed it to `i.getName() for key, i in collidingEnums.items()` seems to work

Comment: Sorry, yeah, it'd be `.values()`

Comment: For whatever reason the `__repr__` thing was the most interesting to learn about. Never seen it before. So many ways to do it in Python, amazing language. Thanks to all.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's bad about `map` in this case?

Comment: @WolframH Generator expressions/list comprehensions are preferred over `map` in general - but in this case specifically, since we're dealing with bound methods rather than plain functions, it makes even more sense. For instance, the generator expression version would work even if not all of the items are `Enum`, as long as they had a `getName()` method.

Answer (score 3):

If you supply the `__repr__` method for you `Enum` class, then it will print whatever you want instead of `<Enum instance at 0x0998F080>`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method on a tuple. If you use collidingEnums.itervalues, you will have a generator of Enum objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better method than using "getName" would be to use the **repr**, **str** or **unicode** functions on the Enum class.

It can be something like this

```
class Enum():
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.getName()
```

Comment: I needed `__str__` for code generation. I didn't know the `__repr__` before. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Since on a dictionary `items` returns pairs `(key, value)` there is no method to call `Enum.getName` *on that pair*. Call it only on the value instead, e.g.

```
print ", ".join(map(Enum.getName, collidingEnums.values())
```

If you want the key displayed, too, use e.g. a `lambda` to work on both parts

```
print ", ".join(map(lambda x: x[0] +":"+ x[1].getName(), collidingEnums.items()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this with `map` using `attrgetter`

```
from operator import attrgetter
print ", ".join(map(attrgetter("getName"), collidingEnums.values()))
```

But since you are passing the result of the map into join, it would be better in this case to use a generator expression with `join()` as Amber suggested